# How do you access certain parts of an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am still fairly new to coding and have been working through some algorithm problems. I have one which tells me to work with arrays, and gives this one as an example:

```
([1, 2, 3, 4], 1.5)
```

How would I access the 1.5 in this example? Or the part in the square brackets, for that matter. Would the part in the square brackets just be accessed through the array name and then [0] or whichever number I wanted to access?

Comment: supposed you mean `var arr = [[1,2,3,4],1.5]` you would access it with `arr[1]`

Answer (score 6):

`([1, 2, 3, 4], 1.5)` is just `1.5` in disguise*, I'm guessing you meant `[[1, 2, 3, 4], 1.5]`. That's an array containing an array (in the first element) and the value `1.5` (in the second). So

```
var a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 1.5];
console.log(a[1]); // 1.5
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 1.5];
snippet.log(a[1]); // 1.5
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

* *"just `1.5` in disguise"*: JavaScript has the *comma operator*, which evaluates both its operands and then uses the one on the right as its value. So `10, 15` is `15`, for instance. (Obscure, but there we are...)

Comment: Thank you! What if I wanted to access the [1, 2, 3, 4] part - would that be console.log(a[0][1]); if I wanted to access the number 2?

Comment: @JasmineBatchellor-Sequeira: Perfect, exactly right. `a[0]` gives you a reference to the array that's in `a`'s first element, and then using `[1]` on that gives you the value of its second element. So `a[0][1]` if you're doing it all in one expression, or `var entry = a[0]; console.log(entry[1]);` if you wanted separate.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what about an alert  :)

Comment: @semirturgay: `alert` is a poor user experience, and the weight of anything else is overkill for such a simple snippet. If SE would [get off their backsides and implement this request from over a year ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239706/add-a-console-to-stack-snippets), I'd use that, but... I went ahead and added a *hidden* snippet.

Answer (score -1):

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>


<script>
var person = [1,2,3,4];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person[0];
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = person[1];
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = person[2];
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = person[3];
</script>
```

output : 1234

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, does it?